# How to query from Glove pre-trained word embeddings?

Tags: python, word2vec

What is the recommended way to query pre-trained Glove (or similar ones) Word Embeddings in Python?

One option I can think of is:

1. Download the whole the pre-trained word embedding vectors from [Glove Page](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/)
2. Put them in a Python dictionary
3. Embed words one by one. (i.e. retrieve the value from the Python dictionary)

Problems with the method above is that one needs to first **copy the whole data to  disk** and then needs to **load 2 Gigs of data to RAM**, which both could be **too expensive**.

Is it the standard way?
Like querying from an online engine?
Or other ways?

Comment: Your content points to zip archive rather than the actual page.

Comment: @dmitryro Fixed. Thanks

Comment: Do we have a tag for glove vector also? I think it's going to be useful to track (at least for me).

Comment: No tag available at this point for Glove. One with enough reputation can make the tag.

Comment: How about (one-time) converting the glove data to a pandas dataframe and saving it as HDF? With HDF format, you can then load only specific keys of the data: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_hdf.html

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to grab only words that appeared in your testing/training corpus and save them separately. That way you don't have to load all other words (3 millions) in the pre-trained vectors.

Comment: How to grab? By performing a linear search on the disk?

Comment: Pretrained vectors are saved as a dictionary (hashset) so it's very quick to grab.

Comment: I think the question ask how can you do it code-wise tho not just explanation.

Comment: @Toussain Louverture No. In the glove page above, zip files contain csv files only. Where do you mean they are saved as a dictionary?